# Generate 1 dto to another dto convertor using freemaker. Stuck at the generating enum type1 to enum type2 convertor

Tags: java, enums, converters, freemarker, generated-code

I am using freemaker to generate dto convertor from one type to another. Defining things through custom annotations
E.g:

```
@CustomAnnotationTargetDTO(type=DTO2)
Class DTO1 {

@CustomAnnotationTargetProperty(propertyName="gender")
private String sex;

}
```

like this I have invented different annotations that I use to map a class and its properties to other type.

I now have a Enumeration in a DTO. Any idea on the similar lines that how i map 1 type to another.

I was thinking on the lines

```
@CustomAnnotationTargetEnum(xmlEnum="Type2Enum")
public enum Type1Enum {

    @CustomAnnotationTargetEnumValue(enumValue="GIRL")
    FEMALE(Byte.valueOf("1")), 
    @CustomAnnotationTargetEnumValue(enumValue="BOY")
    MALE(Byte.valueOf("2"));
//other stuff below

}
```

Comment: So, what's the question? Where's the problem?

Comment: Turns out i can do something like this
String field = Type1Enum.FEMALE.toString();
Type1Enum.class.getField(field).getAnnotation(CustomAnnotationTargetEnumValue.class);